# Integrating $\frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x^2}$

Tags: integration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Evaluate the integral: $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x^2+1} dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155941/evaluate-the-integral-int-01-frac-lnx1x21-dx)

I am a bit stuck here in evaluating the following integral:$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm dx$$.Your help is appreciated.

Comment: This is A5 from Putnam 2005. Different solutions are available at http://amc.maa.org/a-activities/a7-problems/putnam/-pdf/2005s.pdf

Comment: @Michael Biro, I am speechless. This question is actually in a high school textbook!(the question is definitely many years old)

Comment: @Chris when you say it is in a high school text book, does it happen to be Larson, Hostetler, and Edwards, which includes Putnam problems in it?

Comment: No, it is not even an American text.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Put $x=\tan t$ so that $x=1$ corresponds to $t=\frac \pi 4$, and $x=0$ to $t=0$. Hence,

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx=\int_{0}^{\frac \pi 4}\frac{\log(1+\tan t)}{(1+\tan^2t)}\sec^2t dt=\int_{0}^{\frac \pi 4}\log(1+\tan t)dt$$

Let $I=\int_{0}^{\frac \pi 4}\log(1+\tan t)dt$, then:

$I=\int_{0}^{\frac \pi 4}\log(1+\tan(\frac \pi 4- t)dt$ using $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-x)dx$ ([Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80754/show-that-the-value-of-a-definite-integral-is-unity/80776#80776))

$I=\int_{0}^{\frac \pi 4}\log\left(1+\frac{1-\tan t}{1+\tan  t}\right)dt$

$I=\int_{0}^{\frac \pi 4}\log\left(\frac 2{1+\tan  t}\right)dt$

$I=\log 2\int_{0}^{\frac \pi 4}dt-\int_{0}^{\frac \pi 4}\log\left(1+\tan  t\right)dt$

$I=\log 2(\frac \pi 4-0)-I$

Hence $2I=\frac \pi 4 \log 2$

Comment: Why did you factor out the $\pi/4$ while it wasn't an exponent?

Answer (score 7):

A thought: Notice $$\int\limits_0^1 \frac{\log(1 + x)dx}{1 + x^2} = \int\limits_0^1 \frac{\log(1 + x)dx}{1 + 2x -2x + x^2} = \int\limits_0^1 \frac{\log(1 + x)dx}{(x+1)^2 - 2x } \int\limits_0^1 \frac{\log(1 + x)dx}{(x+1)^2 - 2(x+1) + 2}$$ Now put $u = x + 1$ and so youll have

$$\int\limits_1^2 \frac{\log(u)du}{u^2 - 2u + 2} = \int\limits_1^2 \frac{\log(u)du}{(u-1)^2 + 2} = \int\limits_1^2 \log(u)d[\arctan(u-1)]$$

Now use integration by parts..

Answer (score 5):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188732/methods-to-evaluate-int-a-b-frac-ln-left-tx-u-right-mx/188828#188828). You can get the answer in terms of the dilogarithm function $Li_s(z)$

$$\frac{i}{2}{Li_{2}} \left( \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\,i \right)-\frac{i}{2}{Li_2} \left( \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\,i \right) +\frac{1}{4}\,\pi \,\ln  \left( 2 \right) -{\it Catalan}= 0.2721982614 \,,$$

where $\mathrm{Catalan}= 0.9159655942 $ . See here for the [technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188732/methods-to-evaluate-int-a-b-frac-ln-left-tx-u-right-mx/188828#188828). To use the mentioned method, first, use the change of variables $t=x+1$

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm dx= \int_{1}^{2} \frac{\ln(t)\,dt}{(t-(1+i))(t-(1-i))} \,.$$

Note that, this is a general technique which can handle more general integrals.