# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{1} dx\frac{\log(1+x)}{1 + x^2}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Evaluate the integral: $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x^2+1} dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155941/evaluate-the-integral-int-01-frac-lnx1x21-dx)

$$\int_{0}^{1} dx\frac{\log(1+x)}{1 + x^2}$$

I am having a hard time deriving the answer, $\frac{\pi}{8} \log(2) $.  I have tried Taylor expansion of both numerator and denominator, both seem too complicated and fruitless.

Comment: Well, it is a messy looking thing, see: [WolframAlpha - Integral above](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BLog%5B1%2Bx%5D%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%29%2C+x%5D). I also verified over your integration range, and it checks out.

Comment: It is a problem from Putnam.I can't remember which.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220746/integrating-frac-log1x1x2

Comment: @RichardNash, (A5 of Putnam '05)  amc.maa.org/a-activities/a7-problems/putnam/-pdf/2005s.pdf

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let $x = \tan(t)$. Then we get that
\begin{align}
I & = \int_0^1 \dfrac{\log(1+x)}{1+x^2} dx = \int_0^{\pi/4} \dfrac{\log(1+\tan(t))}{\sec^2(t)} \sec^2(t) dt\\
& = \int_0^{\pi/4} \log(\sin(t) + \cos(t)) dt - \int_0^{\pi/4} \log(\cos(t)) dt\\
& = \int_0^{\pi/4} \log\left( \dfrac{\sin(t) + \cos(t)}{\sqrt{2}} \right) dt + \int_0^{\pi/4} \log(\sqrt{2}) dt- \int_0^{\pi/4} \log(\cos(t)) dt\\
& = \int_0^{\pi/4} \log(\cos(t-\pi/4)) dt + \int_0^{\pi/4} \log(\sqrt{2}) dt- \int_0^{\pi/4} \log(\cos(t)) dt\\
& = \underbrace{\int_{-\pi/4}^{0} \log(\cos(t)) dt}_{(t-\pi/4) \to t} + \int_0^{\pi/4} \dfrac{\log(2)}2 dt- \int_0^{\pi/4} \log(\cos(t)) dt\\
& = \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \log(\cos(t)) dt}_{t \to -t} + \dfrac{\pi}8 \log2- \int_0^{\pi/4} \log(\cos(t)) dt\\
& = \dfrac{\pi}8 \log 2
\end{align}

Comment: Very nice, I didn't see it!

Comment: From the second expression in the first line:

$\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\left(1 + \tan\left(t\right)\right)\,{\rm d}t = {1 \over 2}\left[\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\left(1 + \tan\left(t\right)\right)\,{\rm d}t + \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\left(1 + \tan\left({\pi \over 4} - t\right)\right)\,{\rm d}t
\right]={1 \over 2}\left[\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\left(1 + \tan\left(t\right)\right)\,{\rm d}t + \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\left(2 \over 1 + \tan\left(t\right)\right)\,{\rm d}t
\right]={1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\left(2\right)\,{\rm d} t={1 \over 8}\,\pi\ln\left(2\right)}$.