# Integral of $8\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log (1+x)}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

So we got this problem 
$$8\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log (1+x)}{1+x^2}dx$$ 
I have been stuck on this problem for days basically I tried everything I could think of to solve this integral i tried substituting 
$$x=\tan p$$ and integral became 
$$8\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log (1+\tan p)}{1+\tan^2 p}(\sec^2 p)\, dp$$ 
then I was stuck at $$8\int_{0}^{1}{\log (1+\tan p)}\,dp $$
now nowhere to go from here 
can you suggest me another way to approach this problem ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220746/integrating-frac-log1x1x2/220754#220754

Comment: I collected a few integrals of this type 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542477/further-our-knowledge-of-a-certain-class-of-integral-involving-logarithms

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use $$\log(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1} x^n}{n}$$ and argue why one can interchange integral and sum.