# Integration dependent on the ir/rationality of a,b

Tags: definite-integrals

Let $$\text{I(a,b)}=\int _0^1\frac{\ln(1+x^a)}{1+x^b}$$ where $a=\text{irrational},b=\text{rational}$. Can this integral have a closed form ie definite value at some special $a's,b's$?

Comment: I can't answer in general, but a fairly famous problem from an old Putnam exam asks you to evaluate $I(1,2)$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1875684/how-to-evaluate-the-following-integral-int-01-frac-log1x1x2dx/1875735#1875735

Comment: There are formulas using dilogarithms, which I would not consider a closed form solution.

Comment: See Herglotz integrals, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522913/are-there-other-cases-similar-to-herglotzs-integral-int-01-frac-ln-left1t and there, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426325/evaluate-int-01-frac-log-left-1x2-sqrt3-right1x-mathrm-dx?rq=1