# Evaluating $\int\limits_0^{\pi/4}\log(1+\tan x)\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Can someone give me a hint on how to evaluate the closed form of the following integral? According to Wolfram Alpha, this evaluates to $\dfrac{\pi}8\log(2)$.

$$\int\limits_0^{\pi/4}\log(1+\tan x)\,\mathrm dx$$

Thanks.

p.s - Hints are preferred over complete solutions.

Comment: Hint: write x=pi/4 -x....by using property

Comment: Then write 1=tan(pi/4).....then use formula of tan(a)+tan(b)

Comment: At last you will probably have to use properties of log.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220746/integrating-frac-log1x1x2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. By the change of variable
$$
x=\frac{\pi}4-u, \qquad dx=-du, \qquad 1+ \tan x=? \qquad \log(1+ \tan x)=?
$$

Answer (score 6):

$$I=\int^{\frac{\pi }{4} }_{0}\ln\left( 1+\tan  x \right)\ dx=\int ^{\frac{\pi }{4} }_{0}\ln\left( 1+\tan \left( \frac{\pi }{4} -x\right) \right)\ dx=\int^{\frac{\pi }{4} }_{0}\ln\left( 2\right)\ dx-I$$
So we have 
$$2I=\ln\left( 2\right) \int ^{\frac{\pi }{4} }_{0}\ dx=\ln\left( 2\right) \times \frac{\pi }{4} $$
Hence we get$$ I= \boxed{\frac{\pi }{8} \ln\left( 2\right)} $$

Comment: It is essentially the Oliver Oloa's answer.

Comment: @MarcoCantarini yes. But I think this would help those who can't complete the answer.

Comment: +1. It's always fine to show the answer at the very end.

Comment: @FelixMarin  thanks sir  ^_^

Comment: @RefaatM.Sayed You're welcome. Sometimes I'm struggling along an answer to find the final result. It motivated my previous comment. *_*

Answer (score 1):

The post asks for a hint, but that was quite a while ago. For the sake of the site, I think a full answer might be useful:
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\pi/4}\log(1+\tan(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/4}\log(\cos(x)+\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_0^{\pi/4}\log(\cos(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\tag1\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/4}\log(\sqrt2\cos(\pi/4-x))\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_0^{\pi/4}\log(\cos(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\tag2\\
&=\frac\pi8\log(2)+\int_0^{\pi/4}\log(\cos(x))\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_0^{\pi/4}\log(\cos(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\tag3\\[6pt]
&=\frac\pi8\log(2)\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $1+\tan(x)=\frac{\cos(x)+\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$
$(2)$: $\cos(x)+\sin(x)=\sqrt2\cos(\pi4-x)$
$(3)$: integrate the constant $\log(\sqrt2)$
$\phantom{\text{(3):}}$ substitute $x\mapsto\pi/4-x$ in the left integral
$(4)$: cancel

Comment: I looked before posting, but didn't find [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/335825), which, although is not the same, can be easily manipulated to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Note

\begin{align}&\int^{\frac{\pi }{4} }_{0}\ln( 1+\tan  x )\ dx
=\frac12 \int^{\frac{\pi }{4} }_{0}\ln( 1+\tan  x )^2\ dx\\
 =& \frac12 \int^{\frac{\pi }{4} }_{0}\ln\sec^2x\ dx 
 + \frac12 \int^{\frac{\pi }{4} }_{0}\underset{2x\to \frac\pi2-2x}{\ln(1+\sin2x)\ dx}\\
 = &\frac12 \int^{\frac{\pi }{4} }_{0}\ln(\sec^2x(1+\cos2x))\ dx
 =\frac12 \int^{\frac{\pi }{4} }_{0}\ln2\ dx=\frac\pi8\ln2
\end{align}