# How to calculate $\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

It's obvious that $$\frac1{1+x^2}\,dx = d(\arctan x)$$
Let $t=\arctan x$,
it becomes 
$$\int_0^{\frac\pi4}\ln(1+\tan t)\,dt = \int_0^{\frac\pi4}\ln\Bigl(1+\frac{\sin t}{\cos t}\Bigr)\,dt$$
which equals to
$$\int_0^{\frac\pi4}\ln\biggl(\frac{\sqrt2\cos(\frac\pi4-t)}{\cos t}\biggr)dt$$
Then I got the right answer in a WRONG way that
$$\int_0^{\frac\pi4}\ln\biggl(\frac{\sqrt2\cos(\frac\pi4-t)}{\cos t}\biggr)dt =\int_0^{\frac\pi4}\Bigl[\ln\sqrt2+\cos(\frac\pi4-t)-\cos t\Bigr]dt$$
$$=\frac\pi4\ln\sqrt2-\Bigl[\sin(\frac\pi4-\frac\pi4)-\sin(\frac\pi4-0)\Bigr]-\Bigl[\sin\frac\pi4-\sin0\Bigr]$$
$$=\frac\pi4\ln\sqrt2$$
But actually,$$\int_0^{\frac\pi4}\Bigl[\ln\sqrt2+\cos\Bigl(\frac\pi4-t\Bigr)-\cos t\Bigr]dt$$
should be $$\int_0^{\frac\pi4}\Bigl[\ln\sqrt2+\ln\cos\Bigl(\frac\pi4-t\Bigr)-\ln\cos t\Bigr]dt$$
and I don't know how to calculate this integral.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220746/integrating-frac-log1x1x2/220754#220754

Comment: The result should be $$\frac{1}{8} \pi  \log (2)$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner they are the same because $\log(\sqrt{2})=\frac12\log(2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just note that $\int_0^af(a-t)dt=\int_0^af(t)dt$ by $t\mapsto a-t$, so your log-cosines cancel, leaving just $\frac{\pi}{8}\ln 2$. Incidentally, we could have avoided the trigonometry with $x\mapsto\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ and averaged the new expression for $I$ with the old, giving $$I=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln 2dx}{1+x^2}=\frac{\pi}{8}\ln 2.$$The Möbius transformation $\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ is a common enough substitution to deserve a name (I don't know one, but I hope someone will leave it in a comment).

Edit: just to make that transformation more explicit, note first that $$\frac{1-\frac{1-x}{1+x}}{1+\frac{1-x}{1+x}}=\frac{1+x-(1-x)}{1+x+1-x}=x,$$so $$y=\frac{1-x}{1+x}=\frac{2}{1+x}-1\implies dx=\frac{-2 dy}{(1+y)^2}\\\implies\int_0^1\frac{\ln (1+x)dx}{1+x^2}=\int_0^1\frac{\ln\frac{2}{1+y}}{1+\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)^2}\frac{2 dy}{(1+y)^2}=\int_0^1\frac{\ln\frac{2}{1+y}dy}{1+y^2}.$$Adding two expressions for $I$, $$2I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln 2 dy}{1+y^2}.$$

Comment: Thank you. By the way, may I have some details about the new method, why the expression would be that? It’s not easy for me to understand it.

Comment: @AKIRA_FuDO I meant $\frac{1-x}{1+x}$, sorry, but I've added some more information.