# I need assistance in integrating $ \frac{x \sin x}{1+(\cos x)^2}$

Tags: calculus

Find the integral

$$ \int_0^{\pi} \frac{x \sin x}{1+(\cos x)^2}$$

Comment: Use the variable change $x=\pi-y$.

Comment: @Chris'sister Would this help ?

Comment: @Amr: yes, since you get the the same integral in the right side with the sign changed.

Answer (score 8):

Integrate by parts:

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\pi} dx\: \frac{x \sin x}{1+(\cos x)^2} &= -\int_0^{\pi} d(\cos{x})\: \frac{x}{1+(\cos x)^2}\\ &= -[x \arctan{\cos{x}}]_0^{\pi} + \underbrace{\int_0^{\pi} dx \:\arctan{\cos{x}}}_{\mathrm{this} = 0} \\ &= \frac{\pi^2}{4} \end{align}$$

Keep in mind that I used the principal branch of the arctangent.

Comment: That's a fast way (+1)

Comment: Thanks, and you got (+1) from me for doing the integral another way.  I think both of us exploited the symmetry, but came across it differently.

Comment: Right. It's a kind of easy problem often met in high school.

Answer (score 5):

**Solution 1**
Let the variable change $x=\pi-y$, and then

$$I=\int_0^{\pi} \frac{x \sin x}{1+(\cos x)^2}\mathrm{dx}=-\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{ y\sin y}{1+(\cos y)^2}\mathrm{dy}+\pi\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin y}{1+(\cos y)^2}\mathrm{dy}$$
$$I=-\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{(\cos x)'}{1+(\cos x)^2}\mathrm{dx}$$
$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}[-\arctan(\cos x)]_0^{\pi}=\frac{\pi^2}{4}$$

**Solution 2 (the fast way)**

We recall and employ the formula

$$\int_0^\pi xf(\sin x )\mathrm{dx}=\frac \pi2\int_0^\pi f(\sin x )\mathrm{dx}$$

that I used in another answer you may see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220777/faster-way-to-compute-the-integral/220888#220888). Then
$$\int_0^{\pi} \frac{x \sin x}{1+(\cos x)^2}\mathrm{dx}=-\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\pi} \frac{(\cos x)'}{1+(\cos x)^2}\mathrm{dx}=\frac{\pi}{2}[-\arctan(\cos x)]_0^{\pi/2}=\frac{\pi^2}{4}$$
$\quad$

Comment: Thanks,but i was specifically instructed to use other methods other than that...

Comment: @SabrinaAhmed: well, you didn't specify that in your question.

Comment: Sorry about that. But do you think there's another way?

Comment: @SabrinaAhmed: then check rlgordonma's answer that approached the problem differently.