# Why $\int_{0}^{\pi}\arctan{\cos{x}}dx = 0$?

Tags: calculus

I saw this in Ron Gordon's answer to this question:

[I need assistance in integrating $ \frac{x \sin x}{1+(\cos x)^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296548/i-need-assistance-in-integrating-fracx-sin-x1-cos-x2#comment644899_296568)

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Odd around $\pi/2.$ That is, given $f(x) = \arctan \cos x,$ we have $f(\pi - x) = -f(x).$ Draw a graph.