# $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{2x(1+\sin(x))}{1+\cos^2(x)} \mathrm d x$

Tags: definite-integrals

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{2x(1+\sin(x))}{1+\cos^2(x)} \ \mathrm dx$$

**My attempt:**

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{2x(1+\sin(x))}{1+\cos^2(x)} \ \mathrm dx =\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{2x}{1+\cos^2(x)} \ \mathrm dx+\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{2x\sin(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)} \mathrm dx$$
$$=0+\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{2x\sin(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)} \ \mathrm dx$$

I'm not sure how to proceed further. Integration by parts doesn't seem promising. Neither does any substitution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use $x\to a+b-x$.

Comment: Thats just substituting $-x$ right?

Comment: Yes, you got it. After that add both the integrals.

Comment: Its an even function. Hows that gonna help?

Comment: The integral is even so you just have $2 \int_0^\pi \frac{x \sin x}{1 + \cos^2 x} \mathrm d x$. For this integral, see this question: [I need assistance in integrating $ \frac{x \sin x}{1+(\cos x)^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296548/i-need-assistance-in-integrating-fracx-sin-x1-cos-x2).

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3x/439856#439856

Comment: @TobyMak it did help. Also how is $\frac{xsinx}{1+cos^2x}$ not even?

Comment: It is even, so just ignore C Squared's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{2x\sin x}{1+{\cos}^2x}\,dx=2\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{2x\sin x}{1+{\cos}^2x}\,dx$$

Now replace $x$ by $\pi-x$ and add the integrals.

Comment: That helped. Thanks