# Finding the limit of a sequence defined as an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits, indefinite-integrals

I have two sequences defined in terms of an integral:
$$a_n=\int_{-n\pi}^{n\pi}\sin x\,dx$$
$$b_n=\int_{-2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}\sin x\,dx$$
And I am tasked with finding the limit as $n$ approaches infinity. I am not really sure how to achieve this. I have looked at another question on this site that is relatively similar and they used substitution however I have no idea what I should let $u$ equal to make this work out nicely and I did not see this explained.

Comment: The integrals are easy to find

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80754/show-that-the-value-of-a-definite-integral-is-unity/80776#80776

Comment: Wait, so can I just find the definite integral in terms of the FTC and then find the limit of that? That seemed way to easy

Comment: Yeah. That is easy. Now as a bonus, can you tell the value of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(x)dx?$

Comment: I'd say it doesn't exist because the limit as a approaches infinity $\int_{0}^{a} sin(x) dx$ doesn't exist? Even though they would seem to cancel out

Comment: @LiChunMin Cauchy PV says 0?

Comment: I thought that those were two different things. That the limit diverges even though the Cauchy PV is 0?

Comment: It depends on how you define the integral as @Parcly Taxel has pointed out. You may look at what Cauchy PV mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First evaluate the integrals:
$$a_n=\int_{-n\pi}^{n\pi}\sin x\,dx=[-\cos x]_{-n\pi}^{n\pi}=0$$
$$b_n=\int_{-2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}\sin x\,dx=[-\cos x]_{-2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}=2$$
Both $a_n$ and $b_n$ are constant sequences, so their limits as $n\to\infty$ are 0 and 2 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually compute the integral and express $a_n$ and $b_n$ without using the integral. Note that
\begin{align*}
a_n=\int_{-n\pi}^{n\pi}\sin(x)\ dx&=\left.-\cos(x)\right|_{-n\pi}^{n\pi}\\&=-\cos(n\pi)+\cos(-n\pi)\\&=-\cos(n\pi)+\cos(n\pi)\\
&=0,
\end{align*}
so $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n = 0$.

Again, using the fact that $\cos$ is a periodic function with period $2\pi$, note that
\begin{align*}
b_n=\int_{-2n\pi}^{\pi+2n\pi}\sin(x)\ dx&=\left.-\cos(x)\right|_{-2n\pi}^{\pi+2n\pi}\\&=-\cos(\pi+2n\pi)+\cos(-2n\pi)\\&=-\cos(\pi)+\cos (0)\\
&=2
\end{align*}
so $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} b_n = 2$.

Comment: I have corrected your answer which previously was incorrect. Probably you went offline after posting this answer.

Comment: Thank you, @JaideepKhare. I stupidly think of $\cos(0)$ as 0 haha.

Comment: lol...it happens with me too!